# Are there plans for Adobe to support Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe

I'm a Web Developer and also Ubuntu user for some time. Ubuntu is my favorite and only one distribution I use. I work with Debian also but Debian is the best for server and Ubuntu for Desktop and laptop. Sad thing for me that I still need to use Windows just only because There is no chance to install Adobe CS5.5 package on Ubuntu. I tried with Wine but I wasn't successful. Also Adobe customer service informed me that installing Adobe package on Linux is illegal. Is there are any plans for changes? Is there are any chances for compatibility in near future?

Comment: This is more of a Adobe question and not so much a Ubuntu question. The support for what you are asking depends entirely on Adobe which as you mention is illegal and they will most likely not want to do it anyway.

Comment: Like the idea? https://getsatisfaction.com/adobe/topics/produce_creative_suite_for_linux

Answer (score 9):

That's entirely up to Adobe to decide. I would suppose that it mostly depends on how much work it would be for them to port it to GNU/Linux and how many licenses they would have to sell in order to cover the cost of doing so. I personally would also consider the large amounts of free marketing they'd get by porting it, but it might not be part of the equation at all.

Then again, for all we know, they're already working on it, and want to add it to the software center. Or perhaps they're waiting for others to make the platform more popular, and then they'll decide to port it.

In other words; it's entirely Adobes decision, and only they can answer that question.

Answer (score 5):

You should ask to Adobe, not here :)

Answer (score 4):

According to Adobe, there is no plans. They have asked before if there is a interest. I signed it,  but nothing came of it. 
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4194553
Here is a number that you can contact them them directly about support for Adobe. 
http://computer-support247.com/adobe-support.html